# Are PHP file writing operations linear or asynchronous?

Tags: php

I'm wondering because I have a script that writes to the same temp file in a loop. Would that be the best way to go about it?

Comment: Linear, in general.

Comment: Look up what is php and provide us more information

http://php.net/manual/en/intro-whatis.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP in general in synchronous.